# Show / hide mobile menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code for toggling menu for the mobile devices in a responsive site.

It toggles the menu for less than 500 px browser width.

Html:

```
  <div class="mobile-button" style="display:none;">
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="mobibtn">Menu</a>
  </div>

  <nav>
       <div class="main-menu">
            <div class="menu-inner">
                 <ul class="top-nav">
                     <li class="first"><a href="anchorfast-guard.html">ANCHORFAST GUARD<br><span>Oral Endotracheal Tube Fastener</span></a></li>
                     <li class="second"><a href="anchorfast.html">ANCHORFAST<br><span>Oral Endotracheal Tube Fastener</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="clinical-benefits.html">CLINICAL BENEFITS</a></li>
                     <li><a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                     <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
  </nav>
```

jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if (windowWidth < 500) {
    $('.main-menu').hide();
    $('.mobile-button').show();

} else {
    $('.main-menu').show();
    $('.mobile-button').hide();
}
});

$(window).load(function() {
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if (windowWidth < 500) {
    $('.main-menu').hide();
    $('.mobile-button').show();

} else {
    $('.main-menu').show();
    $('.mobile-button').hide();
}
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mobibtn').click(function() {
     $('.main-menu').toggle();
});
});
```

For less than 500 px width, when mobile-button is clicked it shows the menu but hides while resizing.  I want to retain its visibility while resizing if the menu already displays.

Available at http://anchorfast1.com/test/index.html

Comment: Why not use media queries? `(max-width: 500px)`?

Comment: Media queries already used in CSS

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you save the state of the button so you can take its state into consideration in the `window.resize` event handler. Something like:

```
$('#mobibtn').data('state', false).click(function() {

     //toggle the layout
     $('.main-menu').toggle();

     //toggle the saved state
     $(this).data('state', !$(this).data('state'));
});
```

Now you can use `$("#mobibtn).data('state')` to determine whether or not the mobile menu button has been clicked.

Comment: I can't understand it. Can you please inform how to use it in the above code?

Comment: @Paramasivan If you use the above code for the `click` event handler for your menu icon, then you can use `$("#mobibtn").data("state")` (which is set to either `true` or `false`) in your `window.resize` event handler logic. Basically test that value to see if the menu is already open or not so you can leave the correct elements showing or hiding.